# Why tomcat reply HTTP 1.1 respose with an HTTP 1.0 request?

Tags: http, tomcat

Request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
User-Agent: Axis2
Host: localhost:8000
Content-Length: 539
```

Response from tomcat:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 19 Oct 2013 00:28:57 GMT
Connection: close
```

From tomcat website it says:

> If the client (typically a browser) supports only HTTP/1.0, the
>   Connector will gracefully fall back to supporting this protocol as
>   well. No special configuration is required to enable this support.

How Tomcat gracefully fall back to HTTP 1.0? From my example it still reply HTTP 1.1. Can anyone explain to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The protocol version indicates the protocol capability of the sender. It does not specify the version of the response itself. So as long as the response can be understood by the HTTP 1.0 client, Tomcat is doing exactly what it should.

It's all in [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.1)...

Edit: And it's even in the [Tomcat documentation itself](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html#HTTP/1.1_and_HTTP/1.0_Support), right after the part you quoted:

> This Connector supports all of the required features of the HTTP/1.1 protocol, as described in RFC 2616, including persistent connections, pipelining, expectations and chunked encoding. If the client (typically a browser) supports only HTTP/1.0, the Connector will gracefully fall back to supporting this protocol as well. No special configuration is required to enable this support. The Connector also supports HTTP/1.0 keep-alive.
>
> **RFC 2616 requires that HTTP servers always begin their responses with the highest HTTP version that they claim to support. Therefore, this Connector will always return HTTP/1.1 at the beginning of its responses.**

Comment: But the sender has indicated HTTP 1.0, why response is not HTTP1.1? What if client supports only HTTP/1.0? How could Tomcat gracefully resolve it? That's what I don't understand

Comment: Tomcat _is_ sending an HTTP 1.0 compatible response. Tomcat is just telling the client "by the way I support HTTP 1.1". As long as HTTP 1.0 clients can read the response from Tomcat (no matter what it says the version is) you don't have a problem.

Comment: I read it. I thought it was not relevant to my question so I didn't paste it. Now I understand.